# Sort Laravel (4.2) Collection by multiple fields

Tags: php, sorting, laravel-4

How can I sort a Laravel Collection by multiple fields?

Imagine I have an "Exams" model, with a relation to "Patients", with date and score fields.

```
$exams = Exam::all();
$exams->load('Patient');
```

Now I want to sort this Collection by the patient name and then by the date of the exam.

```
$exams = $exams->sortBy('patient.name');
$exams = $exams->sortBy('date', 'desc');
```

This doesn't work, it ignores the first sortBy.

How can I achieve this?

Many thanks! :)

Comment: On your first line `$exams = Exam::all();`, you're already querying and loading all exams.

Then, on your second line `$exams->load('Patient');` you hydrate the `Patient` relationship of all your exams...

That's far too late to trying to sort something.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Hope it helps you.

```
   $exams = Exam::with(
        ['patient' => function($query) {
            $query->orderBy('name')
            $query->orderBy('date','desc)
          }
        ])
    )->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to join patients.

Something like:

```
$exams = Exam::newQuery()
    ->join('patients', 'exams.patient_id', '=', 'patients.id')
    ->orderBy('patients.date', 'DESC')
    ->get()
;
```